# Failed to fetch wine

Tags: updates, wine

Tried to install wine package on Ubuntu 17.04. Run :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

after the `update` got :

```
Fetched 89,2 kB in 1s (51,5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Or
[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCwob.png)

How can i resolve my problem?

Comment: First you should remove that PPA which is not for your release. Then you can install Wine from the official repositories.

Comment: ok, but i thought, it was an official one.

Comment: It goes up to 16.04 only and no, the official repositories are the Ubuntu ones. Most PPAs are managed by third parties.

Comment: Wine 1.8.7 is available at the official repositories. If you need other versions or different version depending on the specific Windows software, using PlayOnLinux (also available at the official repositories) is recommend to manage it (with containers).